# Moving an element from one DOM to another DOM

Tags: html, dom, google-chrome-extension

This is a huge longshot but I'll try anyway :-) 
Suppose that in a Chrome Extension I have two pages (say, the options page and the popup page) and I want to move a DOM object between them (say, an iframe playing a YouTube movie). Is there any way to do that?

Comment: 100% you can pass it like string

Comment: You can't move an iframe without loosing its state, even within the same page. Is the YouTube player used to show a video, or just used as an audio player?

Comment: The youtube-in-an-iframe was an example. My whole context is quite different. My actual need is to pass a webview which plays a youtube video from one page to another. @RobW, if it was an audio player I would have placed it in the background page.

Comment: @EldadMor If the elements were simple nodes, then you can easily transfer the nodes between your popup and options page. However, since your code involves a plugin (Flash for YouTube videos), the option does not produce the desired result, because the plugin/iframe/whatever embed will reload when it's moved within/across documents.

Comment: @RobW - Thanks, I thought as much. Bummer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the inner htlm via

```
saved_html = dom_node.innerHTML
```

Having the dom node as a string, you can save it in localStorage or as a cookie (not sure which works in a chrome extension). At the other page, you load it into a container:

```
container.innerHTML = saved_html
```

Notice: the state won't be saved, so if you play the video it will be still paused on the other site. Also you can't access innerHTML of an iframe if it's not on your domain.

Comment: Yeah well, this is one of many ways to serialize and deserialize the element, but it's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to take the element and move it to a different DOM (btw, both DOMs are on the same domain) while making it behave exactly the same as before.